# C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4　GoToCellDialog 作成時にエラーが発生します。

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

`Qt Creator 4.7.0` を用いて、上記タイトルの本を読みながら、コードの実行を試みています。3個目の例なのですが、エラーが出ます。

`Rapid Dialog Design`という章
`gotocelldialog`を作成する事が目的です。

`Example`ファイルは[こちら](http://www.informit.com/store/c-plus-plus-gui-programming-with-qt4-9780132354165)からダウンロード可能です。
`pdf`ファイルは[こちら](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/215458943_C_GUI_programming_with_Qt_4)から無料公開されているようです。

デバッグを開始するとこうなります。
一応本の指示に従ってコードを書いて、UIファイルも作っているつもり
なのですが、エラーが出ます。
もしかするとバージョンの違いでしょうか？
ご丁寧に、Qt Creatorは或る程度自動でコードを付与してくれて、
とても助かりますが、本の内容とずれているように思えるところがあり、
これは正しいかどうかわからないです。
`Qt`のバージョンは、`5.9.6`です。
**生じるエラー**
[image: わけがわからない]
`gotocell.pro` file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-09-08T09:20:46
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui widgets

TARGET = gotocell
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        gotocelldialog.cpp

HEADERS += \
        gotocelldialog.h

FORMS += \
        gotocelldialog.ui \


# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**gotocelldialog.h**

```
#ifndef GOTOCELLDIALOG_H
#define GOTOCELLDIALOG_H    
#include <QDialog>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QSpacerItem>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "ui_gotocelldialog.h"    
namespace Ui {
class GoToCellDialog;    
}    
class GoToCellDialog : public QDialog, public Ui::GoToCellDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT    
public:
    explicit GoToCellDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~GoToCellDialog();    
private:
    Ui::GoToCellDialog *ui;
private slots:
    void on_lineEdit_textChanged();
};    
#endif // GOTOCELLDIALOG_H
```

**gotocelldialog.cpp**

```
#include "gotocelldialog.h"
#include "ui_gotocelldialog.h"
#include <QtGui>
GoToCellDialog::GoToCellDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::GoToCellDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QRegExp regExp("[A-Za-z][1-9][0-9]{0,2}");
    lineEdit->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(regExp,this));
    connect(okButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(accept()));
    connect(cancelButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(reject()));
}
void GoToCellDialog::on_lineEdit_textChanged()
{
    okButton->setEnabled(lineEdit->hasAcceptableInput());
}

GoToCellDialog::~GoToCellDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "gotocelldialog.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    GoToCellDialog *dialog = new GoToCellDialog;
    dialog->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**gotocelldialog.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>GoToCellDialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="GoToCellDialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>249</width>
    <height>115</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Go to Cell</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
       <property name="text">
        <string>&amp;Cell Location</string>
       </property>
       <property name="buddy">
        <cstring>lineEdit</cstring>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
     <item>
      <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
        <size>
         <width>40</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </spacer>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="okButton">
       <property name="enabled">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>OK</string>
       </property>
       <property name="default">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="cancelButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Cancel</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>lineEdit</sender>
   <signal>textChanged(QString)</signal>
   <receiver>GoToCellDialog</receiver>
   <slot>on_lineEdit_textChanged()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>160</x>
     <y>27</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>127</x>
     <y>55</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
 <slots>
  <slot>on_lineEdit_textChanged()</slot>
 </slots>
</ui>
```

Comment: あ、ついタイトルを編集してしまいましたが、「C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4」という本を見ながらQt 5の学習をしているということですね。

Comment: @soramimi その通りです。編集はいくらでもご自由にお願いします。

Comment: @soramimi せっかく編集いただいたのですが、せっかくですのでロールバックさせていただきました。バッジいただきです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご提示いただいた例では、`gotocelldialog.ui`から`ui_gotocelldialog.h`が自動生成され、`gotocelldialog.h`によってインクルードされます。

UIを定義している`Ui::GoToCellDialog`というクラスを、その動作を実装するための`GoToCellDialog`クラスから利用するには、「継承」または「集約」のどちらかの方法で、UIのクラスを実装のクラスに取り込んでやる必要があります。両方ではなく、どちらか一方しか選べません。

そこで、`gotocelldialog.h`を見てみると、次の記述があります。

```
class GoToCellDialog : public QDialog, public Ui::GoToCellDialog
```

これはクラスの継承です。さらに下の方を見ると、

```
private:
    Ui::GoToCellDialog *ui;
```

これは集約です。繰り返しますが、継承か集約のどちらか一方しか使用できません。

`GoToCellDialog`クラスのコンストラクタで、次のように

```
    ui(new Ui::GoToCellDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
```

`ui`ポインタが初期化されていますが、続く3行では、

```
    lineEdit->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(regExp,this));
    connect(okButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(accept()));
    connect(cancelButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(reject()));
```

のように、`ui`ポインタではなく、継承した方の未構築のUIオブジェクトに対して、初期設定をしようとしており、ここでエラーになります。

修正方法としては、まず、クラスの定義で、UIクラスの継承を止めます。

```
class GoToCellDialog : public QDialog, public Ui::GoToCellDialog
```

↓

```
class GoToCellDialog : public QDialog
```

実装側では、`ui`ポインタを利用してUIオブジェクトにアクセスします。

```
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(regExp,this));
connect(ui->okButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(accept()));
connect(ui->cancelButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(reject()));

ui->okButton->setEnabled(ui->lineEdit->hasAcceptableInput());
```

---

別解として、集約を使わずに継承でやりたい場合、次はそのまま残し、

```
class GoToCellDialog : public QDialog, public Ui::GoToCellDialog
```

次は削除、

```
private:
    Ui::GoToCellDialog *ui;
```

次も削除、

```
    ui(new Ui::GoToCellDialog)
```

次も削除、

```
    ui->setupUi(this);
```

次も削除、

```
    delete ui;
```

以上どちらの方法でも結構ですが、最近は、集約（`ui`ポインタを使う方）が主流だと思います。

Comment: さらっと読ませていただきました。大まかにいうと、`uiDialog`をせっかく作成しているのに、通常の`Dialog`の継承をいろんな場所で参照してしまっているということでしょうか？

Comment: UIオブジェクト（Ui::GoToCellDialog）が継承と集約の混在によって複数作られており、初期化されていない方にアクセスしたためクラッシュしますので、UIオブジェクトを一つにする必要があります。

Comment: 私がどうこう言うよりやってみた方がいいですね。やってみたらうまくいきました。ありがとうございます。おっしゃられることの意味はだいたいわかりますが、まだ集約という事についての経験がありません。出直してきます。

Answer (score 1):

＃すでに回答承認されていますが、QtCreatorの観点で回答加えます。

QtCreatorでは、クラスへの(フォームの)UIクラスの埋め込み方をカスタマイズできます。

「オプション」メニューの「ツール」「オプション」で表示される「オプション画面」から、「C++」「Qtクラス生成」タブを選択すると「UIクラスの埋め込み方法」を選択することができます。
選択肢は、

- ポインタ型のメンバとして集約 (※初期値)
- 集約
- 多重継承

の3つです。「多重継承」を選択すると、参照している書籍のコード例と整合が取りやすくなるかと思います。

＃書籍のコード例は全般的に「多重継承」で実装しているように見受けましたので。