# C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 SortDialog作成時にエラーが発生します。

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

[C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4　gotocelldialog-作成時にエラーが発生します](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48204/c-gui-programming-with-qt-4-gotocelldialog-%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99)

と似た質問なのですが、ご勘弁ください。この質問でご回答いただいたように、
したつもりなのですが、今度は、

**認識できない型　Ui::SortDialogが使われています。**
Ui::SortDialogの宣言を確認してください。

というエラーが出ます。以前の回答の通りに倣って見たのですが、
スムーズにはいきませんでした。

色々とコードをいじってみて実行してみましたが、
糸が絡まるばかり。以下のコードはできるだけもとに戻して
いるつもりですが、どこをどうすればエラーが解決するのでしょうか。
特に、
`sortdialog.cpp`内の`ui->`に下線が。
`delete` に下線が引かれます。
他は事前のエラーの兆候は見受けられません。

```
Windows-10 Qt5.9.6 Qt-Creator4.7.0
```

**sort.pro**

```
    #-------------------------------------------------
    #
    # Project created by QtCreator 2018-09-08T16:20:41
    #
    #-------------------------------------------------

    QT       += core gui widgets

    TARGET = sort
    TEMPLATE = app

    # The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
    # any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
    # depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
    # deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
    DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

    # You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
    # In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
    # You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
    #DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

    CONFIG += c++11\
            uitools

    SOURCES += \
               main.cpp \
            sortdialog.cpp

    HEADERS += \
            sortdialog.h

    FORMS += \
            sortdialog.ui

    # Default rules for deployment.
    qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
    else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
    !isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**sortdialog.h**

```
#ifndef SORTDIALOG_H
#define SORTDIALOG_H
#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_sortdialog.h"
namespace Ui {
class SortDialog;
}
class SortDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SortDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~SortDialog();
    void setColumnRange(QChar first,QChar last);
private:
    Ui::SortDialog *ui;
};
#endif // SORTDIALOG_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "sortdialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   QApplication a(argc, argv);
    SortDialog *dialog = new SortDialog;
    dialog->setColumnRange('C','F');
    dialog->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**sortdialog.cpp**

```
#include "sortdialog.h"
#include "ui_sortdialog.h"
#include <QtGui>


SortDialog::SortDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SortDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->secondaryGroupBox->hide();
    ui->tertiaryGroupBox->hide();
    layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);

    setColumnRange('A','Z');

}
void SortDialog::setColumnRange(QChar first,QChar last)
{
    ui->primaryColumnCmbo->clear();
    ui->secondaryColumnCombo->clear();
    ui->tertiaryColumnCombo->clear();

    ui->secondaryColumnCombo->addItem(tr("None"));
    ui->tertiaryColumnCombo->addItem(tr("None"));

    ui->primaryColumnCombo->setMinimumSize(
                ui->secondaryColumnCombo->sizeHint());
    QChar ch = first;
    while (ch <= last){
        ui->primaryColumnCombo->addItem(QString(ch));
        ui->secondaryColumnCombo->addItem(QString(ch));
        ui->tertiaryColumnCombo->addItem(QString(ch));
        ch = ch.unicode() + 1;
    }
}
SortDialog::~SortDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**sortdialog.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>secondaryGroupBox</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="secondaryGroupBox">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>427</width>
    <height>468</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Sort</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QGroupBox" name="primaryGroupBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>30</y>
     <width>221</width>
     <height>131</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="title">
    <string>&amp;Primary Key</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>178</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
     <item row="1" column="0">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Order:</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="2">
      <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
        <size>
         <width>48</width>
         <height>18</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </spacer>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Column:</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="1" colspan="2">
      <widget class="QComboBox" name="primaryOrderCombo">
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Ascending</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Descending</string>
        </property>
       </item>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QComboBox" name="primaryColumnCombo">
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>None</string>
        </property>
       </item>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>200</y>
     <width>221</width>
     <height>101</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="title">
    <string>&amp;Secondary Key</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>62</width>
      <height>15</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Column:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>62</width>
      <height>15</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Order:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="secondaryColumnCombo">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>71</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>None</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="secondaryOrderCombo">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Ascending</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Descending</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QGroupBox" name="tertiaryGroupBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>330</y>
     <width>221</width>
     <height>111</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="title">
    <string>&amp;Tertiary Key</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>62</width>
      <height>15</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Column:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>62</width>
      <height>15</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Order:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="tertiaryColumnCombo">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>71</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>None</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="tertiaryOrderCombo">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Ascending</string>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Descending</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>260</x>
     <y>30</y>
     <width>101</width>
     <height>131</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="okButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>OK</string>
      </property>
      <property name="default">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="cancelButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Cancel</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>13</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="moreButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>&amp;More</string>
      </property>
      <property name="checkable">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>okButton</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>secondaryGroupBox</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>320</x>
     <y>56</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>192</x>
     <y>164</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortdialog.ui`の以下の記述が誤っているためと思います。

```
 <!-- 誤 -->
 <class>secondaryGroupBox</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="secondaryGroupBox">

 <!-- 正 -->
 <class>SortDialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="SortDialog">
```

QtCreatorからは、「デザイン」画面で、ルートである`QDialog`クラスのオブジェクト名を修正することで修正が反映されます。

＃元々付与したかった`secondaryGroupBox`も、適切なクラスオブジェクトに名称付与してください。

＃QtCreatorで「Qt Designer フォームクラス」を作成するようにすると、このあたりの整合を取ってくれると思います。

---

追記

＃`sortdialog.cpp`の`layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);`の箇所で異常終了するのを見逃してました。回答追記します。

`SortDiag.ui`で`SortDiag`に対してレイアウトが指定されていないので、

```
    layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
```

の箇所で`layout()`が`NULL`(`nullptr`)を返してくるため、異常終了すると思います。

「デザイン」画面で`SortDiag`オブジェクトに対しレイアウトを指定することで解消すると思います。

＃参照されているサンプルでは`GridLayout`が指定されていました。

Comment: `sortdialog.cpp`の`layout()->setSizeConstraint`がきっかけでエラーが発生しました。`widget`の`layout()`なのか、`Dialog`自体の`layout()`かで判断が出来ないのだろうか？と思いましたが、`this->`としてみても、同じエラーが起きました。原因は今のところわかりませんが、とりあえず表記のエラーは解決しました。

Comment: ありがとうございました。デザイナーはなかなか階層関係をうまく変更できずてこずっていますが、どんどんレイアウトと親子関係が階層化していったことが原因のようです。次からは気を付けて作るようにします。`Dialog`直下にレイアウトを強制的に入れ込んでやれば、エラーはなくなりました。（ただし出て来たウィジェットはこれまでの苦労を無駄にするものでしたが・・・。）